# How to update column's property value in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

In **ng2-smart-table** I have a one setting like this.

```
name: {
    title: 'Name',        
    filter: true,
    addable: false
}
```

As you can see I have set `addable` false by default. Now in one case I have to make it true.

**What I have tried:**

Try 1:

```
this.settings.columns.name.addable = true;
```

Try 2:

```
let newSettings = this.settings;
newSettings.columns.name.addable = true;
this.settings = Object.assign({}, newSettings);
```

This reset my other data too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved that issue by set a data in new object and pass it to `resolve()`.

```
let data;
data['columnName'] = 'newData';
event.confirm.resolve(data);
```

It works for me. :)